# How to programatically close a view in eclipse application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to programatically close a view in eclipse application.
The view is a introPart with id: myProduct.intro
I tried:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.hideView(page.findView("myProduct.intro"));
```

But it did not work, any other way to do this or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
IIntroPart introPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getIntroManager().getIntro();

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getIntroManager().closeIntro(introPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use more generic way :

```
//Get current page    
IWorkbenchPage wp=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

//Find desired view :
IViewPart myView=wp.findView("myViewId");

//Hide the view :
wp.hideView(myView);
```