# Close Quick Fix pop-up menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I extended the `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ruler.actions` when an `RulerClick` event occurs, to call the QuickFix command `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.correction.assist.proposals`:

```
public class MarkerClickAction extends AbstractRulerActionDelegate {
    @Override
    protected IAction createAction(ITextEditor editor, IVerticalRulerInfo rulerInfo) {
        moveCarretToClickedLine(editor, rulerInfo);
        runQuickFixCommand(editor);
        return null;
    }

    private void runQuickFixCommand(ITextEditor editor) {
        IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) editor.getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);

        try {
            handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.correction.assist.proposals", null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I click a marker the carret moves to the correct line and the Quick Fix menu pops-up.
If I click again on a different marker, the carret moves to the right line, but the previous Quick Fix menu doesn't close and it doesn't open for the current line.

Which is the `id` of the Quick Fix pop-up menu so I can close it with one of the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114703/how-to-programatically-close-a-view-in-eclipse-application)?
Or is there another method to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: Note: pop-up menus aren't views and don't have an id. No idea how you would do this.

Comment: @greg-449 Apparently that's also how java Quick Fix works, so I think I'll leave it as it is :/